# Activating auto tcl command completion for procs

Tags: command-line, tcl, proc

I need to add tcl command completion for user defined tcl procs in my tcl  application.

For example:

```
tcl_shell> proc myproc {} {puts test}

tcl_shell> my
```

When pressed <kbd>tab</kbd> it should complete myproc.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to ask `info commands`. If you keep the characters typed before the tab character in the variable `str`, you can check for matching commands with

```
info commands $str*
```

If it returns more than one match, you don't have enough of a string prefix to unambiguously identify a command (you might want to keep the list of candidates and let the user traverse it by successive tabs). If you don't get any match, the text in `str` isn't the prefix of any known command. If you get one match, that's the command name to complete with.

If you want to complete for namespaces as well, `namespace children` is the command for that.

Example:

```
proc findCommand str {
    set matches [info commands $str*]
    set ns [namespace qualifiers $str]
    set str [namespace tail $str]
    set nses [namespace children $ns $str*]
    foreach ns $nses {
        lappend matches {*}[info commands $ns\::*]
    }
    return $matches
}

% findCommand cl
clock close clear
% findCommand tcl::cl
::tcl::clock::GetJulianDayFromEraYearWeekDay ::tcl::clock::Oldscan ::tcl::clock::ParseFormatArgs ::tcl::clock::GetDateFields ::tcl::clock::microseconds ::tcl::clock::getenv ::tcl::clock::clicks ::tcl::clock::GetJulianDayFromEraYearMonthDay ::tcl::clock::milliseconds ::tcl::clock::ConvertLocalToUTC ::tcl::clock::seconds
```

Documentation:
[info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm),
[namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm)

**ETA**: `tcl::prefix`

Donal Fellows mentions [tcl::prefix](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/prefix.htm) in a comment. It does roughly the same thing but is a little more complicated to use. The complete list of allowed completions must be passed to it as an argument, which on one hand means you must collect it; on the other hand it means that you can limit the set of allowed completions if you wish, or allow non-existing command names (to be handled by `unknown`). It can also prompt the user with a list of completions if the string doesn't match any of them. Example -- user inputs "foo" and the list of commands are the global commands starting with "b" or "c":

```
::tcl::prefix match -message command $cmds $str
bad command "foo": must be bgerror, binary, break, case, catch, cd, chan, clear, clock, close, concat, continue, or coroutine
```

Comment: The `tcl::prefix` command (8.6 or later) can be helpful for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it gives me the list of procs. But can you please let me know how can I bind the findCommand function to be executed whenever user press the <tab>?

Comment: @sampathA: the `findCommand` example is a basic demonstration and not really useful as a handler. The actual handler could possibly use `findCommand` as a helper. Anyway, I'm not an expert on Tk, but it seems you would bind either to the widget you are using as a console or to its class with something like this: `bind X <Key-Tab> completitionHandler`, where `X` is the widget pathname or the class name, and `completitionHandler` is a callback that is aware of the state of the console and has its own logic (or a helper similar to `findCommand`) to recognize commands.